# Calculating $\int\frac{\mathrm dz}{(2z-i)(z+3i)}$ for $C(0,1)$ and $C(0,4)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I can't seem  to understand how to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{\mathrm dz}{(2z-i)(z+3i)}$.

I thought about decomposing it into partial fractions but that didn't work.
Then I looked at the roots of the function: $z=\frac{i}{2}$ and $z=-3i$. Since $3i$ doesn't lie in the domain $D(0,1+\epsilon)$ then the integral is zero?

I want to also investigate the integral around $C(0,4)$

$$\int_{C(0,4)} f(z)dz$$

Again I come to the conclusion that the answer is $0$ and I feel like I am making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Use the residue theorem...

Comment: Residues were not covered as part of my class. The following is a practice question I am trying as exam preperation

Comment: make a partial fraction decomposition of your fraction into two fractions, then apply Cauchy theorem to each one.

Comment: Decomposing into two fractions I get $\frac{3+2z^2}{4z^4+37z^2+9} -i\frac{5z}{4z^4+37z^2+9}$. So I should apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem to these?

Comment: Why these fractions ?! Plainly $k(2/(2z-i)-1/(z+3i))$ for a certain constant $k$...